# Select field value not changing on setState in onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Select value is gotten from `data.RowCount.Value`.  Changing the value is not reflected until the next render.

```
const [data, setData] = ({RowCount: {"Value": 5}})

...
<TextField 
    select 
    value={data.RowCount.Value} 
    onChange={(e) => {
        setData((prev) => {
            prev.RowCount.Value = e.target.value; 
            return prev;
        });
    }}>
    <MenuItem>Item</MenuItem>
</TextField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mutating state, [don't mutate state](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state#treat-state-as-read-only)

[Update a nested object](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state#updating-a-nested-object)

```
        setData((prev) => ({
           ...prev
           RowCount: {
              ...prev.RowCount,
              value: e.target.value
           }
        }))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to update code like this

```
    setData({RowCount: {"value": e.target.value}}) or
    setData(prev => {return {...prev, RowCount: {"value": e.target.value}}})
```